# Why does JSlint return an "Unexpected '.'." error

Tags: javascript, jslint

When I run this code through [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/)

```
(function () { return "helloooo"; }).call();
```

It gives me following error:

> Unexpected '.'.

**Why is that?**

When I assign function to variable, and then call it I get no errors.

This:

```
var cb = function () { return "helloooo"; };
cb.call();
```

Returns no errors.

But, I would like to know why I get error in first place. What Douglas Crockford's sacred rule do I break with first example?

Comment: you might want to try [jshint](http://www.jshint.com) instead, it's less opinionated

Comment: would trying jshint help me understand why jslint returned error in this case? I'm aware of jshint, I was just wondering is there some good practice hidden behind this warning.

Comment: why the down-vote to this question? care to explain?

Comment: @dugokontov not really, I just get the impression that jslint objects to a number of things for no good reason.  What you're doing is perfectly valid, if a little cryptic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a bad thing. JSLint is opinionated, and Crockford thinks that when you are using a function expression inside parentheses then you should either call that method directly or assign it to a variable, because someone else looking at it might get confused between the value of the function and the function as a value itself.

For this situation Crockford recommends:

```
(function () { return "helloooo"; }())
                                   ^^
                          Notice how is the function being called
```

So JSLint doesn't expect anything after the closing parentheses, that's why it said it didn't expect the `.` which you are using to invoke `call()`.

You can look at the [Code Conventions for the Javascript Programming Language](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html) *(by Crockford)* to learn more about this, specifically look for the section about Functions.

Comment: If I run this code in jslint `(function () { return "helloooo"; }).hasOwnProperty("some");` I get same error. So, `call` is not the problem.

Comment: @dugokontov `Call()` it self is not the problem, the problem is using the `.` operator to call a method or access a property on an anonymous function expression.

Comment: could be... but again, calling a method or accessing a property on an anonymous function is valid thing to do... still not sure why jslint considers this bad practice.

Comment: @dugokontov It is not a bad thing. JSLint is opinionated, and Crockford thinks that when you are using a function expression inside parentheses then you should either call that method directly or assign it to a variable, because someone else looking at it might get confused between the value of the function and the function as a value itself.

Comment: I like your comment. If you could put that in answer I would gladly accept it. Also, there is similar question on JSLint community page https://plus.google.com/104786861890674190911/posts/PG7qnx4fERN